# How to add an offset to an index in a *ngFor angular directive?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I want to display some data from a json but i can't simply add an offset to the index and show all te data from a certain offset but get 
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`and the text in the div doesn't appear.

I have already tried to directly add a fixed number in the html file and it works (see the code below). But when it comes to use a variable "offset" (type:number) from typescript that is supposed to be updated with an input, the return type becomes undifined and the error appears. I also tried to use a method in my typescript file instead of doing the addition in the html file, and return the new index but it doesn't work and show the error. I also tried to call the method using `{{addition(i,offset)}}` and put the result in a variable that I use as an index but it still showing the error.

For exemple, this html file is working fine :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let article of data; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="i<(nbElements)">
        <div (click)="checkArticle(data[(i+3)].id)">
            <p class="text-center"> {{data[(i+3)][dataKey]}}</p>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The div reacts to my click and the text appears.

However, this html file is not working, even if the offset is set as 3 (as the html above) using an input in the parent component :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let article of data; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="i<(nbElements)">
        <div (click)="checkArticle(data[(i+offset)].id)">
            <p class="text-center"> {{data[(i+offset)][dataKey]}}</p>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The error appears.

The offset (type:number) is defined in my typescript file this way, and is changed by the parent component and can easily be displayed by the child component using `console.log(offset)`:

```
export class AppColumnComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() offset : number ;
```

I expect the output to be texts showing the articles of my data json, but as I change the offset using an input like that `data[(i+offset)]` the result is an error, maybe it's impossible to use an other index using an other variable that a fixed number ?

Thank you for your support, it's my first post on stackoverflow i hope i did it well ! :)

Comment: It's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) : instead of asking us help on the solution you think is the good one, please explain your original goal.

Comment: Also, if you can, provide a [mcve] on http://stackblitz.com, that would help us repdouce the behavior and give you a reproductible solution.

Comment: Ok so basically, i want to diplay a json using a ngFor loop, and add a pager to it (the offset) so this way, i just have to change the offset from the parent component to display the json from a certain index. Am I clear enough ? :)
Ok i am working on a stackblitz.com example, thanks

Comment: Clear enough, let me make an answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a pagination component, you should not rely solely on your HTML and some bindings.

Your component should have an "advanced" logic, in the sense that it should be able to know when it reaches the end/start of the collection (among other things).

Basically, this goes as follow :

- Get the full collection (let's say 100 items)
- Splice it to your item per page number (let's say 10, so results range is 0-10)
- Test if items exist before the range
- Test if items exist after the range
- Allow/block page changing based on those variables.

This leaves you with

- 1 variable for the collection
- 1 variable (or 1 pipe) for the subset of the collection
- 1 variable for the items per page number
- 1 variable for the offset
- 2 booleans to disable pagination buttons.

Try working with this, and if you still have issues, then please provide a stackblitz with what you have tried !

Comment: Thank you, i will try this and come back to you later ;)

Comment: Hello there !
I almost finished the pagination component but insted of using the splice method, I used the slice method that allows me to keep the exact part of the array that I want to show : 

```

let fistItem = this.offset;
let lastItem = this.offset+this.nbElements;
this.subData = this.data.slice(fistItem,lastItem);

```

Comment: @robiscuit I meant slice myself, just made a typo I guess. Great !

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an index out of bounds.

`data[(i+offset)]` will be `undefined` for the last `offset` amount of elements in your `data` array so you are basically trying to do `undefined.id` which leads to your error.
You should change your method signature to only recieve the index as parameter and handle that case in your component.ts file

Comment: I tryed with ```data[addition(i,offset)]``` defining addition in my component.ts like 
```addition(a:number,b:number):number {
   return(a+b)
} ``` and i still got the undifined error

Comment: Yes, that doesn't make any difference. For example: `data[18]` won't work, if there are only elements from index 0 to 10. Don't call `data[(i+offset)]` in your template, change your `checkArticle` call to `checkArticle(i)` and check with a simple if statement if there is any element at position `i + offset` to handle that situation properly.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean i'm gonna try it too